# How can I make the animals wear pants?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Does anyone know if it is possible for the animals in Animal Crossing: New Leaf to wear pants? I sent a sailor skirt to one of the animals through the mail, and through some research I found that apparently the animals will change into clothes sent to them about a fifth of the time; however, it was unclear whether this 20% chance was merely applied to shirts or what.

Has anyone had success in the endeavor of putting pants onto an animal?

Comment: I've never seen any of my neighbors wearing pants.

Comment: @Mkalafut - You have some stranger neighbours...

Answer (score 3):

The animals in Animal Crossing do not wear pants. They only wear tees or dresses. If you create custom clothing patterns and put them in the Able sisters shop, even if the design is for pants they will wear the design as some kind of top. Bizarre!

Answer (score 2):

The villagers can't wear pants. If you send a letter to a villager that has a skirt or pants attached to it, then they will probably only display it in their house.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have New Leaf but I don't think you can. On City Folk, I sent Becky a hat and she threw it in the trash bin.